Problem with CSS masking using PNG file transparency
UPDATE: I seem to have solved it though I am not confident that my solution is correct.
I put all files on a server.
I reversed the transparency of the mask image. I am using Paintshop Pro (I know, ancient, but usually good enough for what I need - old dog, new tricks, etc.!)
From the server is seems to display OK. I hate it when things "seem" to work but you don't really understand why. The test page also seems to display weirdly on a tablet - too wide and cut off on the right.  But that's probably the usual CSS/responsive stuff that's not there in the simple test version.
Updated server version
Problem using a mask file - the image is not masked, nothing it shown.
I have tried using the image and mask files locally and on a server - same problem.
It works using a linear gradient mask but not with a transparent mask PNG file.
I have used red as the non-transparent area of the PNG file to make it stand out.
The same problem occurs if the non-transparent area is white.
I have added the HTML/CSS file and images to:
This is an online version of the problem.
Images:
Moorland test image
Mask PNG transparency file
Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>Minimal</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      body {
        margin: auto;
        background-image: url("moorland.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
      .mask1 {  
        -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(black, transparent);
        mask-image: linear-gradient(black, transparent);
      }
      .mask2 {
        -webkit-mask-image: url("mask.png");
        mask-image: url("mask.png");
        mask-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <img src="mask.png">         <!-- This mask goes over the background image -->
                                 <!-- This proves the mask transparency works  -->
    <p>Above shows the background image masked - proving the mask file transparency is working.</p>

    <p>Below show the mask image PNG file - the central ellipse is transparent.</p>
    <img src="mask.png">
                                 
    <p>Below should show the image masked with with linear gradient.</p>
    <div class="mask1">          <!-- Invoke the "mask1" class with linear gradient -->
      <img src="moorland.jpg">   <!-- Display image - should be masked -->
    </div>

    <p>Below should show the image masked using the mask.png file.</p>
    <div class="mask2">          <!-- Invoke the "masks" class using mask file -->
      <img src="moorland.jpg">   <!-- Display image - should be masked -->
    </div>

    <p>Below should show the image without a mask.</p>
    <img src="moorland.jpg">     <!-- Display image with no mask -->
  </body>
</html>

Trying to mask a JPG image using PNG transparency file. Linear gradient masking works, transparency doesn't. I have tried both local and server based files.
